# How to keep a Sidechain up to date with well known static singleton contracts?

Tags: contract-deployment, eip, sidechain

it becomes more and more common in the Ethereum ecosystem to have contracts that only need to exist one time - and all other DApps/Contracts are interacting with this one contract instance.

Here are some examples:

- 0xce0042B868300000d44A59004Da54A005ffdcf9f [EIP-2470 Singleton Factory](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-2470)
- 0x1820a4B7618BdE71Dce8cdc73aAB6C95905faD24 [EIP-1820 Pseudo-introspection Registry Contract](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-182)
- 0xdca7ef03e98e0dc2b855be647c39abe984fcf21b [EIP 1056: Ethereum Lightweight Identity](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-1056)

I am wondering now, if there is a full list available, maybe even a tool that is able to automatic deploy those contracts, if they are missing on a specific sidechain.

Yeah of course, there is always the questions: Who decides what contract is important enough to be expected on a sidechain.
But i guess all EIP's are ?!
I have already started developing a tool that is able to do that by fetching the deployment  bytecode from Ethereum Mainnet. but i still need a list :-)
Is there any consens on that ?
If there is, the List could be provided on Ethereum Mainnet :P
Do you guys know any other effort in this direction ?

Comment: Something like https://github.com/miguelmota/solidity-create2-example ?

Comment: @Markus-soliditydeveloper.com actually most of this singleton contracts are deployed using a one-shot account, without having someone the private key. so no use of Create2. I guess it is possible to create2 as well for deploying cross chain on the same address, but haven't tried it yet. I just take the Raw transaction from ETH-Main and replay it on the sidechain.